# 'cap deploy' doesn't restart puma but 'cap deploy:restart' does

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

After upgrading my `ruby` from `2.2.4` to `2.4.1` I starting facing this issue.

My server would be down after a `cap deploy`, but doing a `cap deploy:restart` just after works.

`Capfile:`

```
require 'capistrano/puma'
require 'capistrano/puma/jungle'
```

`deploy.rb:`

```
# ...

namespace :deploy do

  # after :restart, :clear_cache do
  #   on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
  #     # Here we can do anything such as:
  #     # within release_path do
  #     #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
  #     # end
  #   end
  # end

  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      invoke 'puma:restart'
    end
  end

  before :starting,     :check_revision
  # after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
  after  :finishing,    :cleanup
  after  :finishing,    :restart

  # https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake#capistrano
  after :finished, 'airbrake:deploy'
end
```

Any help on how to diagnose the issue would be great as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `capistrano-puma` gem in gemfile(skip if already added):

```
gem 'capistrano3-puma' , group: :development
```

Then, install the `Capistrano::Puma` plugin by adding the below line in **Capfile**:

```
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma
```

This will include all necessary **puma** libraries.

And also, make you have set the puma config in `deploy.rb` file as below:

```
set :application,     'test-app'
...
...
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
```

Now, try deploying your app.